# Use the scroll mode in gnu-screen without blocking the running program?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, blocked

Is there a way to use the scroll mode in gnu/screen without blocking the running program?

With scroll mode, I mean the ctrl+a ESC key combination which allows you to navigate in the buffer with the arrow keys.

If that mode is active, the running program will be blocked when it wants to write to the terminal until you are finished.

I can modify the program that is being blocked, so a solution requiring change of the source code (instead of some screen settings) is alright as well.